# for line in sys.stdin does not return any value

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

I have a simple python program as below:

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin.readlines():
    print (line)
```

I am working on a mac with os x el capitan. I have Python 2.7.10

When I run this on the program on the terminal, it hangs. It does not print the line.

The image below describes the issue. The command has been running in the terminal fro more than 5 min, yet no outuput

Please help me understand the issue.

Thanks
[image: Image of the terminal]

Comment: Command line arguments != STDIN.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is trying to read from stdin, which means you need to at least `pipe` something into the stdin, here I changed your code slightly and named it after script.py:

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin.readlines():
    print (line,1)
```

And here is the output in shell:

```
$printf "hello\nworld\n" | python script.py
('hello\n', 1)
('world\n', 1)
```

The stdin, stdout, and err are three important concepts in unix in general, i would recommend you to read [more](http://www.linfo.org/stdio.html) about it. Say for example, [Hadoop Streaming](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/) actually leverage stdin/stdout so you can use any language to write map reduce jobs and easily connect different components together.

Here are a few examples of how to get your code working if you have a file.

```
$ printf "hello\nworld\n" > text
$ cat text
hello
world
$ cat text | python script.py 
('hello\n', 1)
('world\n', 1)
$ python script.py < text
('hello\n', 1)
('world\n', 1)
```

Comment: Thanks. that worked, But this is the first time I am using it this way. Before it used to take the stdin without pipe. surprising!